# Looking to purchase a single-volume Mishna

Tags: product-recommendation, mishna

I would really like to buy a copy of the Mishna that I can carry around with me. It absolutely needs to be in print (sorry, I'm not interested in digital versions) and it needs to be in a *single* volume - ideally, small and relatively lightweight. There are dozens of copies of Tanakh so printed, but I cannot find a single one of the Mishna. Do they even exist? It goes without saying that it wouldn't have any commentaries.

If anybody knows of somebody selling such a text, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several mishnayot in 1 volume. there is Kav venaki in Mir edition [here](http://www.lehmanns.co.uk/mwnivt-em-pirvw-qb-vnqi-bkrk-ahd-mir.html), there is a new "Mishna daf leyom' with a new perush based on Bartenura. In edition Eshkol you have pocket book Mishna Bartenura and Ykar Toyt, The same in Edition Chorev (may be out of print), You have [Mishna sedura](https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F-%D7%9B-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93/) (if you can read microscopic letters)

Comment: @DoubleAA in the same setting there are also 1 volume But anyway I assume that the requiest is a poket book, E.G. [this](http://seforimcenter.com/Shisha-Sidrei-Mishnah--Complete-in-One-Volume-with-Peirush-Bartenura__p-10692.aspx) I have it at home is very voluminous and +- 1kg, so it is better to buy 6 little pocket booklets than an enormous 1 volum

Comment: Thank you, Kouty! After looking into it a little bit more, the Mir edition with Kav v'Naki is exactly what I was looking for. (I would *prefer* a version with no commentaries whatsoever, but I think that might be asking for too much. At least Kav n'Naki is minimal and unobtrusive.)

Comment: @ShimonbM it is also not expansive, not enormous, good printed. Ale vehatslach "בתחבולות תעשה מלחמה, .....משניות חבילות חבילות"

Comment: I just want to thank you again! My Mir edition arrived this afternoon and it is *precisely* what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @ShimonbM A great hatslacha!!!

Comment: @ShimonbM I want also to say you thank you thanks to you I learned the topic of 70 71 72 for bet din, many many years this was not clear for me until I begin to write the topic, and this despit that all this gm and mishnayot was known for me

Comment: I know this isn't the place for an extended chat, but I just want to thank you again for your answer. You would have no way of knowing this without my telling you, but it has *massively* improved my revision of the Mishna (I am now on my 15th time through). Thank you again :)

Comment: שתזכה ללמוד משניות חבילות חבילות.   שתזכה לשנן את הש''ס 101 פעמים. תודה רבה

Answer (score 3):

I found this for Hebrew
http://seforimcenter.com/Shisha-Sidrei-Mishnah--Complete-in-One-Volume-with-Peirush-Bartenura__p-10692.aspx

and this for English
[http://www.amazon.com/Mishnah-New-Translation-Jacob-Neusner/dp/0300050224](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300050224)

Comment: I would not advise the translations of Jacob Neusner; he is notorious for tweaking them to prove his thesis. I've mentioned this elsewhere on MY.

Comment: Just like every other translator of every other text. Anyway, that edition is hardly convenient to put in a pocket.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very close to what I'm looking for, but (not to be overly picky) it's pretty large (9.75 x 7") and would be a lot smaller if they didn't include the Bartenura. The only reason I'm not selecting this as the best answer is in the hope that someone provides a link to a smaller and more convenient copy... But this is awesome.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - FYI, the Neusner translation of the Mishna is pretty sloppy, but to his credit it's not actually his. He parcelled that one out to his students, which is why it's so shockingly inconsistent.

Comment: @ShimonbM, Danby's translation (despite being authored by a Christian cleric) is superior to Neusner's, both linguistically and because it does not have a thesis to prove.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - Danby's translation is excellent, as is Blackman's. I'm only really interested in the Hebrew, however. (I should have noted that in the original question.)

Comment: @ShimonbM, makes sense. FWIW, my father has a pocket-sized, three volume set by Eshkol. Each volume's about the size of pocket Rinat Yisrael, assuming they still make it.